# awn_core' could not be found in project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\deali\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\awesome_notifications-0.7.5-dev.1\android\build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':awesome_notifications'.

> Project with path ':awn_core' could not be found in project ':awesome_notifications'.

Update library
invalidate
delete pub cache

Answer (score 2):

intl:^0.17.0
Down this

Actually. Dependency overrided intl:^0.18.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).